MudBlazor Navigation Menu Hover and Click Issue
I'm working on a navigation menu using MudBlazor and have encountered an issue with the hover and click effects. I'm trying to apply a hover effect to the entire container of each navigation link, but the effect is only applied to the MudNavLink itself. Additionally, there seems to be a double hover effect which looks odd.
Here are the styles I'm using:
<style>
    .mud-nav-link:hover:not(.mud-nav-link-disabled){
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-item-container:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .mud-navmenu.mud-navmenu-default .mud-nav-link.active:not(.mud-nav-link-disabled){
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-item-container.active .mud-nav-link.active {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
    }

    .fixed-nav-menu {
        width: 310px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-item-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }

    .nav-item-container .mud-icon-button {
        margin-left: auto;
        transition: color 0.3s;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: grey;
    }
           
    .nav-item-container .mud-icon-button svg {
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }

    .mud-nav-link,
    .mud-nav-group {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .history-section {
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .clear-button-container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 260px;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
</style>


@page "/navmenu"
@using MudBlazor

<MudNavMenu Class="fixed-nav-menu">
    <MudNavGroup Text="[ABC] Report Incident" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Report">
        <div class="nav-item-container">
            <MudNavLink Href="#main-page" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Home">
                Main Page
            </MudNavLink>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarBorder" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item-container">
            <MudNavLink Href="#my-approvals" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CheckCircle">
                My Approvals & Actions
            </MudNavLink>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarBorder" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item-container">
            <MudNavLink Href="#new-assessment" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Assessment">
                New Assessments
            </MudNavLink>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarBorder" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item-container">
            <MudNavLink Href="#my-records" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Folder">
                My Records
            </MudNavLink>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarBorder" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item-container">
            <MudNavLink Href="#risk-summary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help">
                Risk Summary
            </MudNavLink>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarBorder" />
        </div>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>


couldn't give the original solution as it was too big but tried to mimic the problem
The issue:
When I hover over the nav-item-container, the background color is not applied to the entire container.
The hover effect seems to apply twice, which looks odd.
When I click the MudNavLink, the hover effect is only applied to the MudNavLink, not the entire container.
Could someone help me understand how to make the hover and click effects apply to the entire container consistently? Any guidance on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!


